# Update Form <Select> and other async values

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

## Update Form  and other async values

### My Problem

I have a really simple `<select>` input in my reactive form. Inside the select I have multiple users shown like this

```
<div *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
...
<select class="select"
  [formControl]="uid">
  <option [ngValue]="null">select user by email</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of users"
    [ngValue]="user.uid">
    {{user.email}}
  </option>
</select>
</div>
```

It all works pretty good - the only issue I am having is, that the select view where for the user only gets updated after I change a random input.

#### before changing input

[image]

#### after changing random input (can just be a click in a field and then a click out)

[image]

### My question

How can I "refresh" the view on the user automatically after all users have been loaded? Something like

`this.users$ = this.auth.users$.pipe(tap() => uid.refresh())`

Thank you very much in advance and greetings from Germany :)

Comment: Have you tried calling change detection?
It would be nice to have simple example in stackblitz to play around

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem in stackblitz but it would work... for a possible solution, I tapped into the stream and found out I receive two values: First it's just one email adress (in my case it's mine) and then it's everyone elses in the document collection. I am using firebase with shareReplay() on the current user. I don't know if this is a bug...

Comment: Even recreating the problem with fake async observables that emit after one another doesn't recreate the problem.... take a look if you want  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rsofpq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have encountered similar issue before, the one I had was related to change detection mechanism. When we interact with any input inside the view Angular runs change detection, thus, most probably, you are able to see full list after interacting with any input element. 

Check how you load initial data for the form and when do you re-load/update it.

Comment: Yes! I think that is exactly the problem but my question here is... how can I implement a re-load/update or update it? Is there a line of code to run change-detection? I could think of places where I could implement a reload but don't know how I can do such a thing.

Comment: You may inject `ChangeDetectionRef` intro your components constructor and use it to manually call change detection as follows:

`constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef) {}

     // somewhere inside component methods
     getEmailList() {
      ...
      this.cdr.detectChanges(); // if you retrieve list from API make sure you do change           
     detection after you renew variable that stores the list
     }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223682/discussion-between-oleg-kuibar-and-obstfliege).